# When I am create a case with account lookup using post menthod I am getting this error

Tags: apex

[image]

Can anyone let me know wherr I am wrong and what should I use to create lookup account

Comment: Wow, photograph of your computer screen. Please include your code and error message as ***text*** rather than an ***image***.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write this in another way. It should be

```
accountId = account
```

account is string which you are passing in your method and accountid is case field.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation:

[image]

You need to reference the AccountId instead of Account